# What is included in C Standard library?

Tags: c, linux, posix, standards, language-lawyer

I will give an example from [The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Opening-and-Closing-Files) documentation:

> 13.1 Opening and Closing Files
>
> This section describes the primitives for opening and closing files
>   using file descriptors. The open and creat functions are declared in
>   the header file fcntl.h, while close is declared in unistd.h.

My question is:

Can `unistd.h` and `fcntl.h` be considered as Standard C? As far as I know, they should be part of the [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nframe.html)?

Can we say C Standard Library = Posix functions + C API? I am confused because [Wikipedia page for C Standard Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) does not include `unistd.h` but the GNU C Library documentation includes it?

Comment: The C standard has a section about the C standard library as well. Check out http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.pdf for the C11 standard.

Comment: No, `unistd.h` and `fcntl.h`, etc are not part of standard C.

Comment: @YuHao Why are they included in the The GNU C Library documentation?

Comment: `C` is a programming language, POSIX is a operating system specification / API standard -- In a venn diagram you will see that some C implementations support POSIX, but not all do -- nor are they require to do so -- GNU C Lib is in the intersection of implementing both, and then some more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, in `C11` standard, there is no `unistd.h` and `fcntl.h`. So, strictly speaking, they are not part of the `C` standard.

When it comes to the *implementation* part, the [GNU C library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) (`glibc`) is one of them. From the wiki page

> `glibc` provides the functionality required by the Single UNIX Specification, POSIX (1c, 1d, and 1j) and some of the functionality required by ISO C11, ISO C99, Berkeley Unix (BSD) interfaces, the System V Interface Definition (SVID) and the X/Open Portability Guide (XPG), Issue 4.2, with all extensions common to XSI (X/Open System Interface) compliant systems along with all X/Open UNIX extensions.
>
> In addition, `glibc` also provides extensions that have been deemed useful or necessary while developing GNU.

So, as a part of the POSIX standard, they are available in `glibc`.

Reference: Check the `C11` standard [draft version here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: Can you give a reference please, so I can check it as well?

Comment: Why does The GNU C Library include them in documentation?

Comment: Thanks, I will accept once I can. I tought linux itself came with the implementation of the posix?

Answer (score 5):

No, `unistd.h`, `fcntl.h`, etc, are not standard C.

In general, standard C doesn't include functions that deal with low level file manipulation. For example, `fopen`, `fread`, and `fwrite` are part of standard C library. While POSIX `open`, `read`, `write` functions are not standard C.

Comment: Does unix come with its own posix implementation or must the c library implement it? (such as gnu c library..)

Comment: @KorayTugay Any C library for Unix should support POSIX, if that's your question.

Comment: @KorayTugay, POSIX (the modern form of Unix) is an interface specification not an implementation. Linux as an OS is a POSIX  implementation. How an implementation collects the different features is to its discretion. Most Linux distributions use glibc as an implementation of the C (amd POSIX) library, but some don't. Another implementation of the same interfaces is e.g musl.