# About the relation between linux shell's functions and C's functions()

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

For example, I thought the ln command in the shell is implemented by link() and symlink() provided by C,so I checked the src of the ln, but it seems it doesn't utilize them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, many Linux commands are written in C; and many of those C programs might use  C library functions like [link()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/link) or [symlink()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/symlink).  Various Linux shells (e.g. sh, csh and bash) are themselves written in C, and also use C library calls.

HOWEVER...

link() and symlink() are both POSIX-compliant wrapper functions, they're not part of the "Standard C Library". Consequently, The "ln" command doesn't use them. See [unistd.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h) for more details.

See also [What is included in the C standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414198/what-is-included-in-c-standard-library).

Comment: i found “ln” uses symlinkat() and linkat()

Comment: @handeng, you should add that to your question. Indeed, a much better question might be "Why do GNU command-line utilities use `symlinkat` and `linkat` instead of `symlink` and `link`?"

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if any C program on a Linux/Glibc system that uses `link()` etc. ends up actually invoking the `XXXat` syscall version if one exists.